# Instanciar a una clase en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, clase

quisiera saber la forma correcta de hacer una instancia a una clase, en lo que estoy trabajando es consumir la API de Freshdesk pero no muestra nada, agregue la referencia de mi DLL, esta es la clase:

```js
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Freshdesk
{
    public class CreateTicket
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string fdDomain = "edgarrojas13"; // your freshdesk domain
            string apiKey = "XG9o5QEW2HuWfbzaFM8";
            string apiPath = "/api/v2/tickets"; // API path
            string json = "{\"status\": 2, \"priority\": 1, \"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"subject\":\"test\",\"description\":\"confirm whether received\"}";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + fdDomain + ".freshdesk.com" + apiPath);
            //HttpWebRequest class is used to Make a request to a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).  
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest. 
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest. 
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            string authInfo = apiKey + ":X"; // It could be your username:password also.
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

            //Get the stream that holds request data by calling the GetRequestStream method. 
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream. 
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
            // Close the Stream object. 
            dataStream.Close();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Submitting Request");
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                //Send the request to the server by calling GetResponse. 
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access. 
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content. 
                string Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //return status code
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code: {1} {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode, (int)((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode);
                //return location header
                Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", response.Headers["Location"]);
                //return the response 
                Console.Out.WriteLine(Response);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("API Error: Your request is not successful. If you are not able to debug this error properly, mail us at support@freshdesk.com with the follwing X-Request-Id");
                Console.WriteLine("X-Request-Id: {0}", ex.Response.Headers["X-Request-Id"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Status Code : {1} {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode, (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode);
                using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    Console.Write("Error Response: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

y en un proyecto de consola hago la instancia a la clase "CreateTicket" de la siguiente manera:

```html
using Freshdesk;

namespace FreshdeskAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateTicket CT = new CreateTicket();     
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de querer ejecutar mi proyecto de consola, inicia y después no hace nada, no se si me falta algún código mas para que pueda consumir todo el código que esta en la clase "CreateTicket", si me pueden ayudar como puedo utilizar el código de dicha clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, hay un problema con tu clase CreateTicket, ya que el método main no es público. Tienes cambiarlo para la firma quede del siguiente modo:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
          //...
    }
```

Ahora bien, el método que contiene la llamada es un método estático, por lo que no necesitas crear la instancia de la clase. Tienes dos alternativas:

Reemplazar el código de tu programa de consola

```
using Freshdesk;
namespace FreshdeskAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateTicket.Main(); //Acá invocas el método estático.
        }
    }
 }
```

O bien, cambias la firma del método Main de tu clase CreateTicket para que quede del siguiente modo:

```
public void Main()  //Quitamos static
{
      //...
}
```

y con lo anterior, tu programa de consola quedaría así:

```
using Freshdesk;
namespace FreshdeskAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateTicket CT = new CreateTicket(); 
            CT.Main(); //Acá invocas el método Main de tu clase CreateTicket...
        }
    }
 }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me funciono a la perfección!!!

Comment: Por nada... por cierto, espero que tu Key no sea real. Si lo es, tendrás que cambiarla porque ya quedó registrada acá.

Comment: cierto... ya cambie mi Key, gracias nuevamente por la observación